# Binary search function not working

Tags: java, binary-search

I'm new to Java and am just beginning to learn some simple data structures and algorithms. I've been trying to implement a binary search function but I keep getting a stack overflow error and I don't know where it's coming from.

```
public class BinarySearch {
    public static void main (String[]args){
        BinarySearch bs = new BinarySearch();

    int array [] = {1, 8, 6, 91, 52, 74, 5, 9};
    int length = array.length;
    bs.sort(array, 0, length-1);
    bs.print(array);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(bs.binarySearch(array, 0, length-1, 5));
}

public int binarySearch(int array [], int low, int high, int desired){
    int pivot = array[(low+high)/2];
    if(desired<pivot){
        binarySearch(array,low,pivot, desired);
    }else if(desired>pivot){
        binarySearch(array, pivot+1, high, desired);
    }else {
        return (low+high)/2;
    }
    // if element not present in array
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Stack overflow means the stack is full. Your recursive function binarySearch has called itself too many times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has several problems.

1. You aren't returning the result of the recursive call.  Add `return`.

   ```
   if(desired<pivot){
       return binarySearch(...);
   }else if(desired>pivot){
       return binarySearch(...);
   }
   ```
2. Don't mix the index you're checking with the pivot value you're checking.  Calculate the index and use it separately.  Also, use `index - 1` instead of `index` as the `high` when recurring low, to eliminate the current index from future consideration.

   ```
   int index = (low+high)/2;
   int pivot = array[index];

   if(desired<pivot){
       return binarySearch(array,low,index - 1, desired);
   }else if(desired>pivot){
       return binarySearch(array, index+1, high, desired);
   }else {
       return index;
   }
   ```
3. If your low value is greater than your high value, the value wasn't found.  That is your base case, not returning `-1` at the bottom (which is now unreachable code anyway, because every branch of logic above returns a value already).  Place it above your current `if`.

   ```
   int index = (low+high)/2;
   int pivot = array[index];
   if (low > high)
       return -1;
   if ...
   ```

Assuming your `sort` works properly, the above changes should return the index of the element properly, or `-1` if not found.

Answer (score 1):

When I run this I get an `indexoutofboundsexception` because in these lines:

```
int pivot = array[(low+high)/2];
if(desired<pivot){
   binarySearch(array,low,pivot, desired);
}
```

You pass `pivot` as the high, which can be any number in the `array`. And the in the first line in this excerpt you call the index of `high + low`, which can be any number in the `array` plus whatever you originally pass as `low`. So in this example you can be calling the `0 + 92` index of the `array`.

As to the `StackOverflow` it is in this line:

```
if(desired<pivot){
     binarySearch(array,low,pivot, desired);
}
```

Here you pass the exact same parameters in your recursive calls, so if it enters this branch of the `if` loop, it will continue to call the recursive calls until too many of them go onto the stack and there is a Stack Overflow error

Answer (score 1):

**BinarySearch** is used when the array itself is already sorted (in order), which is the foundation of the **BinarySearch** and you already did the *sorting* part.

However there are two obvious problems in your solution:

1. Your problem mainly lies in: `pivot`, you are using the element as the **index** here;
2. include the `mid` when it should be ignored since `if (desired < pivot)`;

Besides, you should try to use `low + (high-low) / 2` to get the middle index (when the size of the array is big enough `low + high` will blow up the `int`) and then get the `pivot = array[mid]` to avoid integer overflow, which is also a better practice to get the middle index.

```
public class BinarySearchBasic {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BinarySearchBasic bs = new BinarySearchBasic();

        int array[] = {1, 8, 6, 91, 52, 74, 5, 9};
        int length = array.length;
        Arrays.sort(array);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(bs.binarySearch(array, 0, length - 1, 5)); // miss;
        System.out.println(bs.binarySearch(array, 0, length - 1, 8)); // hit!
    }

    public int binarySearch(int array[], int low, int high, int desired) {
        int mid = low + (high - low) /2;
        int pivot = array[mid]; // get the middle element;
        if (desired < pivot) {
            binarySearch(array, low, mid - 1, desired); // since it's already smaller, use mid - 1 directly;
        } else if (desired > pivot) {
            binarySearch(array, mid + 1, high, desired); // same reason, use mid + 1 directly to skip mid;
        } else {
            return mid; // bingo!
        }
        return -1; // not found;
    }
}
```

The output:

```
[1, 5, 6, 8, 9, 52, 74, 91]

-1
3
```

Answer (score 1):

You have no base case. Recursion requires a base case to know when to stop recursing. The result of infinite recursion is `StackOverflowException` because you are calling and calling but not returning. You are going to into infinite recursion. The base case of binary search is when `hi` is less than `lo`.

You also want to change your left call to go from `low` to `m-1` rather than pivot because your bounds are inclusive on both ends.

You were also using the pivot **VALUE** as your index! rather than the middle **INDEX**:

```
binarySearch(array, low, pivot-1, desired);
```

Should be:

```
binarySearch(array, low, m-1, desired);
```

Method:

```
public int binarySearch(int array [], int low, int high, int desired) {

    // Not found
    if (high < low) 
        return -1;

    // Middle index
    int m = low + (high - low) / 2;

    // Middle value
    int pivot = array[m];

    if (desired < pivot)
        binarySearch(array, low, m-1, desired);

    else if (desired > pivot) 
        binarySearch(array, m+1, high, desired);

    else 
        return m;

}
```